# To visually compare features/column values of 2 or more entries in a Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, data-science

Is there any plot/graph in matplotlib or seaborn to parallelly compare the numerical column values (varying scale) between two or more entries of a dataframe.

Or is there any workaround to implement this in a barplot or lineplot wthout feature scalling !?